# Android keyboard does not work properly

Tags: android

I have a layout with 2 Edittexts: Email with  requestFocus and password.
When the View is opened, i have no keyboard and I have to click on the password edit text to get it. Do you may be know why?

Comment: Its not mandatory for the keyboard to pop up when a view is active. Keyboards are often programmed to appear on touch of an edittext. Is it working with email field? if its appearing only on touch of password field then its somethings to think about

Comment: you are looking for "requestFocus"

Comment: Thank you Rashmi, in fact, when I am touching the email edittext, nothing appears, when i am touching the password edittext, the keyboard will appear. When i then touch the back hard button, the keyboard go down and works properly for the boths of edittext's..

Answer (score 1):

//To show softkeyboard

onCreate() write the below code

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .showSoftInput(emailedittext, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have found the solution, the problem was the requestfocus written on XML

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, the problem was on the RequestFocus writen on xml.
I deleted this line and now it works.